# How to download a lot of data from Bloomberg?

Tags: bloomberg

I am trying to download as much information from Bloomberg for as many securities as I can. This is for a machine learning project, and I would like to have the data reside locally, rather than querying for it each time I need it. I know how to download information for a few fields for a specified security.

Unfortunately, I am pretty new to Bloomberg. I've taken a look at the excel add-in, and it doesn't allow me to specify that I want ALL securities and ALL their data fields.

Is there a way to blanket download data from Bloomberg via excel? Or do I have to do this programmatically. Appreciate any help on how to do this.

Comment: Whatever way you use (Excel, API etc.) you will still need to list the securities and fields you want - there are thousands of securities and fields - and some fields may return masses of data. You won't find a button that says download Bloomberg's whole DB locally. Also note that there are restrictions as to how much you can download per day and per month so you may hit those limits at some point.

Comment: You can obviously generate your spreadsheet in code. So, if you already know the complete list of securities you want to import, you can generate a big CSV with all the `=BDP(...)` fields you need in it, load it in Excel, save it back as a CSV with the data from Bloomberg, and then import it back into your other system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a request in unreasonable. Bloomberg has dozens of thousands of fields for each security. From fundamental fields like sales, through technical analysis like Bollinger bands and even whether CEO is a woman and if the company abides by Islamic law. I doubt all of these interest you.

Also, some fields come in "flavors". Bloomberg allows you to set arguments when requesting a field, these are called "overrides". For example, when asking for an analyst recommendation, you could specify whether you're interested in yearly or quarterly recommendation, you could also specify how do you want the recommendation consensus calculated? Are you interested in GAAP or IFRS reporting? What type of insider buys do you want to consider? I hope I'm making it clear, the possibilities are endless.

My recommendation is, when approaching a project like you're describing: think in advance what aspects of the security do you want to focus on? Are you looking for value? growth? technical analysis? news? Then "sit down" with a Bloomberg rep and ask what fields apply to this aspect. Then download those fields.

Also, try to reduce your universe of securities. Bloomberg has data for hundreds of thousands of equities. The total number of securities (including non equities) is probably many millions. You should reduce that universe to securities that interest you (only EU? only US? only above certain market capitalization?). This could make you research more applicable to real life. What I mean is that if you find out that certain behavior indicates a stock is going to go up - but you can't buy that stock - then that's not that interesting.

I hope this helps, even if it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

They have specific "Data Licence" products available if you or your company can fork out the (likely high) sums of money for bulk data dumps. Otherwise, as has been mentioned, there are daily and monthly restrictions on how much data (and what type of data) is downloaded via their API. These limits are not very high at all and so, by the sounds of your request, this will take a long and frustrating time. I think the daily limits are something like 500,000 hits, where one hit is one item of data, e.g. a price for one stock. So if you wanted to download only share price data for the 2500 or so US stocks, you'd only managed 200 days for each stock before hitting the limit. And they also monitor your usage, so if you were consistently hitting 500,000 each day - you'd get a phone call.

One tedious way around this is to manually retrieve data via the clipboard. You can load a chart of something (GP), right click and copy data to clipboard. This stores all data points that are on display, which you can dump in excel. This is obviously an extremely inefficient method but, crucially, has no impact on your data limits.

Unfortunately you will find no answer to your (somewhat unreasonable) request, without getting your wallet out. Data ain't cheap. Especially not "all securities and all data".

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to download "ALL securities and ALL their data fields."  You can't.

You should go to WAPI on your terminal and look at the terms of service.

From the "extended rules:"

There is a daily limit to the number of hits you can make to our data servers via the Bloomberg API. A "hit" is defined as one request for a singled security/field pairing. Therefore, if you request static data for 5 fields and 10 securities, that will translate into a total of 50 hits.

There is a limit to the number of unique securities you can monitor at any one time, where the number of fields is unlimited via the Bloomberg API.

There is a monthly limit that is based on the volume of unique securities being requested per category (i.e. historical, derived, intraday, pricing, descriptive) from our data servers via the Bloomberg API.